# pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController is called twice

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

Hope this isn't a duplicate. I tried other solutions found online and none of them seem to fit my issue.

I have a pageViewController that uses scrolling to display 3 tableViewControllers.
The tableViewController holds the index, but the pageViewController increases it or decrements it.

The problem I have is that the viewControllerAfterViewController in the pageViewController datasource is getting called twice when scrolling to a page. This makes the index go from 0 to 2, then from 2 to 1 when scrolling back.

I have tried setting my pageViewController as the delegate as well and use the didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers method, but this also displays the messed up index since the viewControllerAfterViewController method is the one incrementing the counter twice.

Here's my code for the pageViewController:

```
- (TrendsTableViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if ([arrayOfCharts count] == 0 || (index >= [arrayOfCharts count]))
        return nil;

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];

    TrendsTableViewController *tableViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"trends"];
    tableViewController.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
    tableViewController.pageIndex = index;

    switch (index)
    {
        case 0:
            self.title = @"Index 0";
            break;
        case 1:
            self.title = @"Index 1";
            break;
        case 2:
            self.title = @"Index 2";
            break;
    }
    return tableViewController;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((TrendsTableViewController *)viewController).pageIndex;

    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound))
        return nil;

    index--;

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((TrendsTableViewController *)viewController).pageIndex;

    if (index == NSNotFound)
        return nil;

    index++;

    if (index == [arrayOfCharts count])
        return nil;

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return [arrayOfCharts count];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}

- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
{
    TrendsTableViewController *viewController = [previousViewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    NSUInteger index = viewController.pageIndex;
    NSLog(@"index finished = %lu" , index);
}
```

And then my tableViewController, only has this property to keep the index, but doesn't modify it or use it at all:

```
@interface TrendsTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property NSUInteger pageIndex;
@end
```

Any idea on why this method is getting called twice or what I might be doing wrong?
I am compiling for iOS 6 and higher.

**Update:**
To make things more annoying, this code works perfectly fine when I change the transition style from "scroll" to "page curl".
Somehow, "page curl" works fine and the indexes are correct. The only issue is on the "Scroll" transition type.

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the way the page view controller works when you use the scrolling transition. It does this, because it inserts a scroll view into the view hierarchy, and keeps the current as well as the previous (if there is one) and next controllers in the scroll view. You should notice that it only gets called once if you go forward again after the first forward scroll.

Comment: So how do you solve the issue of the index increasing by 2 in the first run?

Comment: I've solved it by not using a page view controller. When I've needed to something similar to what you're doing, I used a collection view with horizontal scrolling and paging enabled. The cells were the same size as the screen, and each cell contained a table view.

Comment: Mmmmm....that's a good idea, but I might give it a bit more time to try to get this working with the pageviewcontroller.
Thanks for the suggestion